# Progess bar in vb.net 2008 while File loading into the grid

Tags: vb.net

I have written in vb.net for progress bar. I am thinking of there is a better way than this.

Here is what my code is :

```
Private Function ImportDataFiles(ByRef pobjDataLoadDTO As DataLoadDTO) As Boolean
        Try
            lblStatus.Visible = True
            lblStatus.Text = ""
            myProgressBar.Visible = True
            myProgressBar.Value = 0
            For Each drRow As ImportData.TRow In pobjDataLoadDTO.FileInfo.Select("categ_code = 'abc'")
                If pobjDataLoadDTO.FileTimes.ContainsKey(drRow.KEY_CODE) AndAlso _
                    pobjDataLoadDTO.FileTimes(drRow.KEY_CODE) > pobjDataLoadDTO.UploadTimes(drRow.KEY_CODE) Then

                    pobjDataLoadDTO.DestinationTablename = drRow.KEY_CODE

                    If mobjDataLoadBO.ImportDataFiles(pobjDataLoadDTO) Then
                        drRow.DATA_TXT = mobjCommonBO.ONow.ToString
                    End If

                End If
                lblStatus.Text = drRow.KEY_CODE.Trim & "is loading...."
                lblStatus.Refresh()
                myProgressBar.PerformStep()
                lblStatus.Refresh()
            Next
            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
```

Right now It is working, But I want to use more efficient way, like using Backgroundworkerprocess...etc.,  Any Ideas on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function runs in main thread, I assume your application is freezing and not very smooth while upload in progress.

1 - Drop Backgroundworker control on the form

2 - set "reportProgress" property of the worker to "True"

3 - Move your loop code into "DoWork" event of the worker control. And call worker.RunWorkerAsync.  You can pass needed arguments to it

4- the code that refreshes progress bar move into "ProgressChange" event of the worker.  This is important as you can't call control from worker thread. and ProgressChange is running in the main thread.  You can also delete "Refresh" method call. That will not be needed anymore.  Every time you want to refresh the progress bar call "ReportProgress" method of the worker

5-Use "RunWorkerCompleted" worker event, to do your clean up, and hide your progress bar

Its also might be a good idea to check if worker is already working before initiating, like

```html
If worker.IsBusy Then
   If worker.CancellationPending = False Then
        worker.CancelAsync()
   End If
   Exit Sub
End If
```